# How to prove this limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have:

$$V_n = \dfrac{1}{2^{n+1}} \cdot\dfrac{\sin{2x}}{\sin{\dfrac{x}{2^n}}}$$

How can I, using $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin{x}}{x} = 1$, prove that:

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} V_n = \dfrac{\sin{2x}}{2x}$$

I have thought about saying that $h = \dfrac{x}{2^n}$, but I can't get it to work out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $h(n)=\frac{x}{2^n}$, then $$V_n = \frac{h}{2x}\frac{\sin 2x}{\sin h}$$

Now I think you should be able to work it out on your own, since you can separate the parts wher $x$ is appearing and the parts where it is not.

Comment: I am going to try this, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite the equation

$$V_n = \dfrac{2x}{2^{n+1}} \dfrac{1}{\sin{\dfrac{x}{2^n}}} \dfrac{\sin{2x}}{2x}$$
$$ =  \dfrac{1}{\frac{\sin{\dfrac{x}{2^n}}}{\dfrac{x}{2^{n}}}} \dfrac{\sin{2x}}{2x}$$

Frome here it should be easy to show what you asked for, as $\frac{x}{2^n} \rightarrow 0$for $n \rightarrow \infty$.